# find not working properly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an easy problem here, but I'm stuck ATM here.

I can't see why a simple `Model::find($id)` is not working.

I have a new application. I checked that the application is successfully connecting to the database.

So I changed the query to something like this:

```
$user = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$id);
```

and it perfectly works, but if I instead do this:

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

it returns nothing, it's null.

My model looks something like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The table associated with the model
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users'; 

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped
     * 
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'picture_id',
        'remember_token',
        'telephone',
        'name',
    ];

    //------DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS------    
    /**
```

What's incorrect there?

---- added model to the question

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The table associated with the model
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users'; 

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped
     * 
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'picture_id',
        'remember_token',
        'telephone',
        'name',
    ];

    //------DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS------    
    /**
     * Each User has one Picture
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function picture()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Picture');
    }

    /**
     * Each User has many Ads
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function ads(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Ad');
    }
}
```

And here an screenshot of the table. I filled it with fake data:

[image]

Comment: Try this `$user = \User::find($id);`

Comment: How are you determining if `DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$id)` returns something?  If I'm not mistaken, this returns a query builder and at first glance, it might look like it's actually returning results if you are `dd`ing it.  Throw `->get()` at the end of that and see if the returned array is empty.

Comment: The database was created running this migration: `Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');`

Comment: I can see all data for that user on screen if I run the raw query but nothing when I do User::find($id).

Comment: Could you post your whole model? Do you get results with `User::all()`?

Comment: `$user = User::all();
        
        dd($user);` returns an empty array

Comment: I've updated the whole model in the description of the question, thanks

Comment: Can you show your database table screenshoot, its structure?

Comment: I' ve just updated it above, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the solution. Here in the table description I saw that the deleted_at column was being updated every time, so all the users were "deleted"
 [image]

I did this to implement a soft delete feature, when we did the migration file, we did this incorrectly:

```
$table->timestamp('deleted_at');
```

which should be

```
$table->dateTime('deleted_at');
```

I modified that column:

```
alter table users modify deleted_at datetime;
```

and updated the current values to NULL:

```
update users set deleted_at = null;
```

Now everything is working fine.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Either use `User` at the top

```
use App\User;
```

or use `\`

```
$user = \User::find($id);
```

Comment: yes, this line is in my controller at the top: `use App\User;`

Answer (score 0):

if id is integer in database then only it wil work in find or else you have to use 
where

```
$user = User::find($id);

$user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
```

Null will return  if you dont have records in table for that id but in your case its there since other DB query will return

Comment: This is not the problem.

Comment: can you post $id value so ican check it

Comment: even if I do $id=1 before running that, it doesn't work with the User::find($id)

Comment: `$user = 1;
        $user = User::find($id);
        
        dd($user); // still returns null`

Comment: can you try where ..$user = User::where('id',$id)->first(); and check it once

Comment: yes, `$user = 1;
        //$user = User::find($id);
        $user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
        
        dd($user);` but still resturns null

Comment: which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: if you are using lumen then you have to enable elequent.i hope you are using laravel

Comment: This is the version:  const VERSION = '5.5.13';

Comment: it's laravel, yes

Comment: cant believe why its not working.if i get sollution for this issue i will post